# Problems with non-"UTF-8" file collection using flume - Spooldir type

Tags: encoding, utf-8, cloudera, flume

My flume spool directory contains non-"UTF-8" files.
So I get a Java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException error when I try to collect it.
Changing the encoding option of a .conf file will also cause an error.
And I have to use spooldir type.
How can I collecrt non-"UTF-8" files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4igE.png)

Answer (score 0):

The encoding of our log files were Latin5 (which is Turkish)

Fixed it by adding the below line into the conf file:

```
AGENTNAME.sources.SOURCENAME.inputCharset = ISO-8859-9
```